# Symfony2 Is it possible to redirect from other places(functions)?

Tags: redirect, symfony, controller, response

Forgive my English.

I want to redirect not from action side but from a other function.

controller

```
public function editAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $article = $em->getRepository('MySampleBundle:Article')->find($id);

    // TODO:
    // Since other actions have the same processing,
    // I would like to do check work in other function. 
    // And when inaccurate,
    // I want to make it move from that function to other page. 
    $this->is_edit_granted($article);

    $form = $this->createForm(new ArticleType(), $article);

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bindRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // ...
        }
    }

    return $this->render('MySampleBundle:Article:edit.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'article' => $article,
    ));
}

public function is_edit_granted($article)
{
    // TODO:
    // I check not at the action side but at this place,
    // and want to make it move from this function to other page. 

    if (!$article) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('No article found.');
    } else if ( $article->getAuthor() != $this->getUser()->getId() ) {
        return $this->redirect( // doesn't work here
            $this->generateUrl('home', array(
                "id" => $article->getId()
            ))
        );
    }
}
```

I also tried similar code:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

class SampleController extends Controller
{
    // ...

    public function editAction(Request $request, $id)
    {
        // ...

        $this->is_edit_granted($article);

        // ...
    }

    public function is_edit_granted($article)
    {
        if (!$article) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('No article found.');
        } else if ( $article->getAuthor() != $this->getUser()->getId() ) {
            return new RedirectResponse(
                $this->generateUrl('home', array(
                    "id" => $article->getId()
                ))
            );
        }
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work.

It is performing in the environment of Symfony 2.1.2. 
How can I manage to achieve that?
Or, is there any better method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do something like:

```
public function editAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    // ...

    $response = $this->is_edit_granted($article);
    if ($response) return $response;

    // ...
}

public function is_review_granted($article)
{
    if (!$article) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('No article found.');
    } else if ( $article->getAuthor() != $this->getUser()->getId() ) {
        return new RedirectResponse(
            $this->generateUrl('home', array(
                "id" => $article->getId()
            ))
        );
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: It worked completely.  
Thank you for the advice you gave me.  
(However, it will become like a double check.(from a personal standpoint)  If possible, I would like to throw all of the check processing out to a other function.)

Comment: You cannot do everything in the other function. If you return from it, you are just returning to the action function which called it. Please, remember to accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to redirect from the `is_review_granted` without returning the `RedirectResponse` form the `editAction`. So the answer of Carlos Granados is correct.

Another option would be to throw an AccessDeniedException in the is_review_granted method:

```
public function is_review_granted($article)
{
    if (!$article) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException('No article found.');
    } else if ( $article->getAuthor() != $this->getUser()->getId() ) {
        throw new Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException('no acces');
    }
}
```

You could also look to some more in-depth solutions like [ACL](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/security/acl.html) and [SecurityVoters](http://kriswallsmith.net/post/15994931191/symfony2-security-voters).

Comment: AccessDeniedException is interesting. 
Well, I should read more documentation......
I appreciate your consideration. 
Thank you for the advice.